# iPhone signal received bad excess in uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

```
- (IBAction)viewNotes:(id)sender {

    NoteListViewController *noteList= [[NoteListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NoteListViewController"
                                                                              bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:noteList animated:YES];    

    NSLog(@"called");
}
```

This is crashing and received Bad_Excess. This code is working fine in other view controller. I also enabled NSZombie but it is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. noteList is propbably not nil, because the app wouldn't crash if you push a nil viewcontroller - instead it would post a warning to the console. It may be crashing before it is being pushed. The code you posted appears fine to me.

So I think it may have something to do with the NoteListViewController's setup - either the nib name has a typo, the nib itself is faulty or there's some other error within the init methods of your VC. I'd suggest stepping through the NoteListViewController init code, if you haven't already done so...

Comment: Thanks for reply.I found the problem I used Nsmutable array in NoteListViewcontroller and I used like tableArray = [NsmutableArray array];  And it should be like self.tableArray = [NsmutableArray array]